# django apache :WSGIPythonHome cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, server, virtualenv

i have a server with ubuntu-server that run apache2 and where i have my django project. i'm having trouble deploying the app. this is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName HIVE.localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/leo/HIVE/src

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/leo/HIVE/src/static
        <Directory /home/leo/HIVE/src/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/leo/media
        <Directory /home/leo/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/leo/HIVE/src/HIVE>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIPythonHome /home/leo/HIVE/HIVE_env
        WSGIPythonPath /home/leo/HIVE/src
        WSGIDaemonProcess HIVE python-home=/home/leo/HIVE/HIVE_env python-path=/home/leo/HIVE/src/HIVE
        WSGIProcessGroup HIVE
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/leo/HIVE/src/HIVE/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

i want to use wsgi to deploy it. i have tried several solutions found on the internet but i couldn't manage to do it. sadly the docs didn't help at all, neither [digital ocean tutorial on this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04). i' stuck with the command *sudo apache2ctl configtest* that gives me the error in the title. i have already changed ownership of the database and the folder where it is contained.

**additional info:**
inside my home directory i have two folders called **HIVE** and **media**. inside **HIVE** a virtualenv folder called **HIVE_env** and a **src** folder. inside src there is my project, inside HIVE_env there is my env ( containing libs and the rest)

i'm new to apache and deploying so this is a lot of new info for me. thank you for your attention.